# How can I add a relation to a different database? [Parse.com]

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've made a friend request system that basically, when **User1** sends **User2** a friend request, in **User1**'s row, **User1** is stored in the column "From" and **User2** is stored in the column "To". There is also another column called "Status" which is automatically set to "Pending", until it's accepted or declined.

Now for **User2**, I have a PFQuery that finds all friend requests (rows where the current user is saved in "To" anywhere in the database). When **User2** accepts the request, my Javascript/ PFCloud Code basically creates a relation for **User1** with **User2** in a column called "Friends" (My Objective-C code creates the relation for **User2** with **User1**). Now this all works fine, except now, instead of the "From", "To" and "Status" columns being in the same database, I have moved them to a different database called "FriendRequests".

The only problem I am having is changing my Javascript code. At the moment it can query the "FriendRequest" database and gather the "To" users, "From" users and "Status" **BUT** I can't get it to create the relation between **User1** and **User2** as they are in the "_User" database.

This is the cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addFriendToFriendsRelation", function(request, response) {

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var friendRequestId = request.params.friendRequest;
var query = new Parse.Query("FriendRequests");
query.get(friendRequestId, {

    success: function(friendRequest) {

        var fromUser = friendRequest.get("from");

        var toUser = friendRequest.get("to");

        var relation = fromUser.relation("friends");

        relation.add(toUser);


        fromUser.save(null, {

            success: function() {

                friendRequest.set("status", "accepted");
                friendRequest.save(null, {

                    success: function() {

                        response.success("saved relation and updated friendRequest");
                    }, 

                    error: function(error) {

                        response.error("Error 1");
                    }

                });

            },

            error: function(error) {

             response.error("Error 2");

            }

        });

    },

    error: function(error) {

        response.error("Error 3");

    }

});

});
```

I am trying to set the `var relation = fromUser.relation("friends");` and `relation.add("to")` to the `"_User"` database.